# Java JUnit Testing Error

Tags: java, junit

This is what I'm doing: Calculate the exact age of a person when given their birth year, month, and date, as well as the current year, month, and date.

You can use this math trick to calculate age!

1. Convert inputed values into this format: YYYYMMDD
2. Subtract the birth information from the current information
3. The first three digits of your answer is the person's age. (Note that in most cases the first digit will be zero)

Example:

```
Birth: 19900510
Current: 20100803
Current - Birth : 0200293
First 3 Digits: 020
This person is 20 years old.
```

This is my main .java file

```
class CodeClass { 
    public int ageCalculator(int birthYear, int curYear, int birthMonth, int curMonth, int birthDay, int curDay) 
    {
        String answer;
        int current = curYear*10000 + curMonth*100 + curDay; 
        int birth = birthYear*10000 + birthMonth*100 + birthDay; 
        answer=Integer.toString(current-birth);
        answer = answer.substring(0,2);
        return(Integer.parseInt(answer));
    }
}
```

This is the JUnit testing file

```
 import junit.framework.TestCase; 
    import org.junit.Test; 
    public class CodeTest extends TestCase { 
      @Test 
      public void testGetNum() { 
            assertEquals(26, CodeClass.ageCalculator(1983, 2010, 4, 4, 5, 2));
            assertEquals(27, CodeClass.ageCalculator(1983, 2010, 6, 10, 15, 1));

      } 
    }
```

This is the error when I run the test

```
Your code did not compile: /CodeTest.java:6: non-static method ageCalculator(int,int,int,int,int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context
        assertEquals(26, CodeClass.ageCalculator(1983, 2010, 4, 4, 5, 2));
                                  ^
/CodeTest.java:7: non-static method ageCalculator(int,int,int,int,int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context
        assertEquals(27, CodeClass.ageCalculator(1983, 2010, 6, 10, 15, 1));
                                  ^
2 errors
```

Comment: ageCalculator() is not a static method.  Either use new CodeClass().ageCalculateor(...) or make ageCalculator() a static method (i.e. public static int ageCalculator(<args>).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `ageCalculator`, which is a  `non-static` method in static way:

```
CodeClass.ageCalculator
```

As per your need either mark the method `static` or create and instance of the class and then call the method on that instance.

Comment: @user2766873 There is a better way to say thanks on stack overflow by accepting an answer. To accept an answer just click on the tick mark led to the answer. Accepting an answer help others also facing the same problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your method `ageCalculator(-,-,-,-,-,-)` in CodeClass class is instance method means non-static that you are trying to access by class name. Only static methods you can access directly using class name. But to use non static method create an instance of your CodeClass class and then call `ageCalculator(-,-,-,-,-,-)` method on that instance or object like below:

```
 import junit.framework.TestCase; 
    import org.junit.Test; 
    public class CodeTest extends TestCase { 
      @Test 
      public void testGetNum() { 
           CodeClass cc= new CodeClass();
            assertEquals(26, cc.ageCalculator(1983, 2010, 4, 4, 5, 2));
            assertEquals(27, cc.ageCalculator(1983, 2010, 6, 10, 15, 1));

      } 
}
```